# Prediction in incorrect days in ARIMA model python

Tags: python, statsmodels, arima

I have a time series dataset. I am using python, pandas and statsmodels to try to forecast the next month of my data.

I have daily data:

[image]

First I run autoarima to see what variables I have to put in my Sarimax model:

```py
auto_arima(df['occurrences'],seasonal=True,m=7).summary()
```

and I obtain this results:

[image]

So, now I split the dataset in train and test data. I want to try to predict the next month, so I do:

```py
train = df.loc[:'2020-04-30']
test = df.loc['2020-05-01':]
```

I train the model

```py
model = SARIMAX(df['occurrences'],order=(1, 1, 1))
results = model.fit()
results.summary()
```

```py
start=len(train)
end=len(train)+len(test)
predictions = results.predict(start=start, end=end, dynamic=False, typ='levels')
```

But now when I plot the predictions I can see how the predictions are one day advanced:

```py
ax = test['occurrences'].plot(legend=True,figsize=(12,6),title=title)
predictions.plot(legend=True)
ax.autoscale(axis='x',tight=True)
ax.set(xlabel=xlabel, ylabel=ylabel);
```

[image]

If I use the shift comand to asing all the predictions one day before:

```py
ax = test['occurrences'].plot(legend=True,figsize=(12,6),title=title)
predictions.shift(-1).dropna().plot(legend=True)
ax.autoscale(axis='x',tight=True)
ax.set(xlabel=xlabel, ylabel=ylabel);
```

[image]

You can see how now are fitted in the correct day, why is happening this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model is giving you the correct predictions on the correct days. ARIMA models are relatively simple and predict the future based on the present and past. So when the model sees a large value today (for example in observation 11), its prediction for tomorrow is larger.

For example, see this StackExchange question and answer: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/330928/time-series-prediction-shifted